# Why does django object.get raise DoesNotExist when it does?

Tags: django

I have got this strange exception : the object exists in my database, `get` doesn't work but filter does...

```
(Pdb) p ProjectPhase.objects.get(slug='done-complete')
*** DoesNotExist: DoesNotExist('ProjectPhase matching query does not exist.',)

(Pdb)  p ProjectPhase.objects.all().filter(slug='done-completed')
[<ProjectPhase: 8 - Done - Completed>]
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 2):

Both texts are different. First one is: `done-complete` and second one `done-completed`.

So,

```
ProjectPhase.objects.get(slug='done-completed')
```

Should work

Comment: lol ok thanks. I have tried to delete my question which is not so useful finally but I can't